# How to convert array and sub array to collection in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I want to convert all of my static data to collection in Laravel.

This is my data:

```
static $menu_list = [
    [
        'path' => 'admin/report/transaction',
        'active' => 'admin/report',
        'name' => 'Report',
        'icon' => 'file-text',
        'children' => [
            'path' => 'admin/report/transaction',
            'active' => 'admin/report/transaction',
            'name' => 'Transaction',
        ],
    ],
];
```

This function converts my data to array:

```
public static function menuList()
{
    $menu_list = collect(self::$menu_list)->map(function ($voucher) {
        return (object) $voucher;
    });
}
```

but function above can only convert main of array, it can't convert `children => [...]` to collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a recursive call.

```
public static function convertToCollection()
{
    $menu_list = self::menuList(self::$menu_list);
}

public static function menuList($list)
{
    return collect($list)->map(function ($voucher) {
        if(is_array($voucher)) {
          return self::menuList($voucher)
        }
        return $voucher;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `collect()` inside `map()` again:

```php
public static function menuList()
{
    $menu_list = collect(self::$menu_list)->map(function ($voucher) {
        return (object) array_merge($voucher, [
            'children' => collect($voucher['children'])
        ]);
    });
}
```

Comment: it return error  Trying to get property 'children' of non-object  on line   'children' => collect($voucher->children)

Comment: Oh, sorry, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a small code peace to your approach.

```
  $menu_list = collect(self::$menu_list)->map(function ($voucher) {
             $voucher['children'] = (object) $voucher['children'];
            return (object) $voucher;
        });
```

**Output**

```
   Illuminate\Support\Collection {#574 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#573 ▼
      +"path": "admin/report/transaction"
      +"active": "admin/report"
      +"name": "Report"
      +"icon": "file-text"
      +"children": {#567 ▼
        +"path": "admin/report/transaction"
        +"active": "admin/report/transaction"
        +"name": "Transaction"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what the thread owner did.

Comment: but he wants ```children``` to be object. Isnt it happen from my code @shaedrich ?

Comment: he says ```it can't convert children => [...] to collection.``` . So my answer works as he wanted.

Comment: No, they want `path`, `active`, `name` and `icon` to be object as far as I can see. And even if you were right, it wouldn't require an answer but a comment that the thread owner does everything right.

Comment: his code base dosent make children as a object

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I missed that.